# Have multiple <input> in <form> | PHP

Tags: php, html

So im trying to to have a download button and a delete button with the same list.
At the moment it's like this:

```
echo '<form action="download.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="download" value="' . $file . '" /> ' .
    $file . '<br /><br />';
}
echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Download" > '  . '</form>';
echo  nl2br (" \n ");
echo  nl2br (" \n ");
echo (" <strong>Delete</strong><br/>Choose only<strong> 1 </strong>! ");
echo  nl2br (" \n ");
echo  nl2br (" \n ");
echo '<form action="delete.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="download" value="' . $file . '" /> ' . $file . '<br /><br />';
}
echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Delete" />' .
'</form>';
```

But i want it to have something like this:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<form action="download.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="download" value="' . $file . '" /> ' . $file . '<br /><br />';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Download" > '  .
    echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Delete" />' . '</form>';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file . '<br /><br />';
    }

'</form>';
```

The "Delete-Button" should go to delete.php and the download button should go to "download.php" with the same "form".

Comment: Using input type=button and set script for them

Comment: Give your buttons a meaningful name and check in the backend which button was pressed and act accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Give each `input` a `name` attribute. Only the clicked input's name attribute will be sent to the server.

```
<input type="submit" name="download" value="Download">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
```

And then ( in the backend file)

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
        # download-button was clicked
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        # delete-button was clicked
    }
?>
```